# No route matches missing required key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am new to Ruy on Rails and i am getting this No route matches  missing required keys: [:id] error and i do not know how to fix it. I have already tried solutions similar to mine but nothing works.

Here are my models

```
class Hall < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_many :fields
        has_many :comments
        end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :hall
      belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base      
    has_many :halls
    has_many :comments
end
```

My routes

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :halls do
  resources :fields 
  resources :comments
  end
```

And _comment.html.erb file where the error is

```
<p><%=comment.content %></p>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_hall_comment_path(comment.hall, comment) %>  <-- error
```

This is the error i get

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :hall_id=>"1", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to `edit` an object that has not yet been saved to the database? You cannot `edit` something before it's been persisted in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i do not think that is the case here because if i remove the line that causes the error i can post a comment and it is then renderd in hall show page.

Comment: You are looping over all the comments right? Can you post the whole loop?

Comment: If you post the comment, then this **saves** it. Your error is because the comment has not yet saved (i.e. `comment.id == nil`), and you are trying to render a route to edit it. Rails cannot generate a route to edit something that does not yet exist.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do here, without seeing more context. Perhaps the `_comment.html.erb` is being used for multiple purposes, some of which don't make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're error is obviously trying to access an edit path without an id.  You might wanna take a look at https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if

Or just make the link conditional. Edit path helper won't work if there is no ID on the unpersisted object.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_hall_comment_path(comment.hall, comment) if comment.id %>
```